# How to write the json file for my code?the parsing data its not displaying in android also?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

i want to parse my data by ROR using Json,i want to parse all the data as name in an array

hotelscontroller.erb

```
respond_to :json, :xml
  def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotels.to_json(:only => [ :name ]) }
    end
  end
```

index.json.erb

```
{
hotel:   <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    { 'name': "<%= hotel.name %>" }
  <% end %>
}
```

I write this code,is this code is correct or wrong,it will parse the name(data) as in array.

This is my parsing Url,

http://peaceful-cliffs-6253.herokuapp.com/hotels.json, in that url i want to parse all the names in an array, how can i do that in my code

My parsing output is showing like this
[
  {
    "name": "karthi"
  },
  {
    "name": "shreshtt"
  },
  {
    "name": "jitu"
  },
  {
    "name": null
  },
  {
    "name": null
  },
  {
    "name": null
  }
]
but i want to show like this model,how can i do like this

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "c200",
      "name": "Ravi Tamada",
      "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender": "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "c201",
      "name": "Johnny Depp",
      "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender": "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "c202",
      "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
      "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender": "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    },
```

its like the above model i want to do,

with the hotel all names have to display

How to display the array of names in android using json,

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://peaceful-cliffs-6253.herokuapp.com/hotels.json";

    // JSON Node names
    //private static final String TAG_HOTEL = "hotel";
    //private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    //private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    //private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    //private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    //private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone"; 
    //private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    //private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    //private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray hotel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            hotel = json.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < hotel.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = hotel.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                Log.e("Name Testing", name);
                //String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                //String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                //JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                //String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                //String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                //String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                //map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                //map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                //map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name,});

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                //String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                //String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });



    }

}
```

This is my client side code also,its not fetches the array of names,i think the problem might be in JSONArray hotel = null;
The output of android displaying only the  plain screen without displaying the names,

Comment: Not sure of understand, you do not need index.json.erb, this is automatically managed by Rails

Comment: Isnt the response there already an Array ? You just want to send an array containing only the names back to the browser ?

Comment: ya ,i want to send tha array back to browser using url,i want to give the array name, inside the hotels it has to display,but its not showing like that,it wil display only the array of name @AlokSwain

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an index.json.erb. Just type it this way in the hotelscontroller.erb:

```
def index
  @hotels = Hotel.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      hash = {:hotels => @hotels}
      format.json { render :json => hash }
    end
```